# Simplifying variable (if condition) with field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, conditional, if-else

I want to simplify the variable (`"SIOSE_CODE"`) which has values like this:

```
A(90MTRfr_05PST_05SDN)
A(65PST_35MTRfr)
A(70FDCfr_10PST_10MTRfr_05MTR_05SDN)
```

The first number (here `90` resp. `65`, resp. `70`) is a percentage of the land-use class which is most frequently at this location.

Now I want to extract the land-use class (`MTRfr`, `PST` or `FDCfr`), but only if the percentage is higher than `60%`.

I tried it with this code:

First I created a new variable `"Percentage"` and filled it with the output of:

```
CASE
WHEN (substr("SIOSE_CODE", 1, 1) = 'A' )
OR (substr("SIOSE_CODE", 1, 1) = 'I')
OR (substr("SIOSE_CODE", 1, 1) = 'R')
THEN (substr("SIOSE_CODE", 3, 2))
END
```

Herethen I want to extract the land-use class:

```
CASE
WHEN ("Percentage" > 55)
THEN (substr("SIOSE_CODE", 5, 100))
ELSE (regexp_replace("SIOSE_CODE", '[(](.*)?[)]', ''))
END
```

But the output of my new variable is `NULL`.

The output of the variable `"Percentage"` seems to be okay.

Does somebody find the mistake?

Comment: Both of your syntax worked for me. I could get *NULL* only when I set the output field type to `number` (integer or real). Could you double-check?

Comment: What type does your `"Percentage"` attribute inherit? Integer or float?

Comment: As @Kazuhito already clarified, I do not see any issues in `"If-statement"`as well.

Comment: I think I would just change this tiny part `THEN (substr("SIOSE_CODE", 5, 100))` into `THEN right("SIOSE_CODE", length("SIOSE_CODE")-4)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just used your code and It works perfectly. I think you need to be careful at selection of the data type.

- First piece of code: select integer
- Second piece of code: select string

[image]
[image]
[image]